# How to setup git automatic deployment with 3 servers [repository, dev, prod]

Tags: git, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, gitosis, automatic-updates

Recently I've read some notes and tutorials [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)  of how to set up automatic deployment with Git. The problem is that all solutions were about 2 servers - test and live, and server for test had to have repository within itself.

In my case - I have 3 servers:

1. server with all repositories [Debian 6.0.8] (using Gitosis)
2. development/test server [ubuntu 14.04] where my team makes changes
3. live/prod server [ubuntu 14.04]

Is it possible to configure auto deployment in this case?

I was wondering about mounting my production server to repository server or make another connection between them somehow.

Maybe there is some better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out to be much easier than it looked like.

1. First, I've mounted my development server to my repository server

> ```
> sshfs user@dev_server:/path/to/www /mnt/dev_server -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o allow_other
> ```

Without allow_other option there is permission denied error on "git push"

2. Than in repositories/website.git/hooks folder I've created script "post-receive"

> `cat post-receive`
>
> ```
>  #!/bin/sh
>  git --work-tree=/mnt/dev_serv/path/to/www/website --git-dir=.../repositories/website.git checkout -f
> ```

And it is working like a charm. Now I am just searching for some more secure approach. This solution was tested between local to dev_server.

The main goal is to run autodeployment only when something is being pushed from dev server - not local - to production.